# There is 1 redirect

Tags: redirect

I tried all the ways to skip this problem , my website on wordpress http://www.b-secrets.ro and I keep getting There is 1 redirect

http://b-secrets.ro/ redirects to https://www.b-secrets.ro/

I change my site to http://wwwb-secrets.ro on phpmyadmin and I have this code on .htaccess

```
#redirect non-www to www
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and this code on wp-config :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.b-secrets.ro');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.b-secrets.ro');
```

and I still this error

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's history completely, or checking with a HTTP header checker? Browsers cache redirects, so even if your update was successful, your browser may just be showing you what it saved previously.

Comment: I got this error Redirect type 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: http://b-secrets.ro [301]

Comment: https://www.b-secrets.ro/ [200]

Comment: A 301 is a status, not an error. The non-www link you posted takes the visitor to the www version as intended. Where is it you're seeing the text that it is 301 redirected?

Answer (score 0):

The 301 redirect is from `http://` to `https://`.

Your rewrite rule specifies `https://` while your `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are set to use `http://`.

That's why you're seeing the 301 redirect from `http://www.b-secrets.ro` to `https://www.b-secrets.ro`.